# Comunicação do c# e C++

Tags: c#, c++

Como posso fazer o código C# chamar uma variável que está em um arquivo de C++ por exemplo. Sabendo que estou utilizando o Visual Studio.

Código C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int test = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

mas como posso acessar essa variável no c#

Comment: Não é possível fazer diretamente no mesmo código fonte... pois o compilador do c# trabalha de uma forma diferente do c++.

Comment: Existem formas de fazer isso, aliás ótima pergunta !

Comment: Bom eu tentei com o qt mas foi um completo fracasso de fazer uma gui entao resolvi usar o c# so que eu precisaria urgentemente disso, mas os tutoriais dos foruns sao bem antigos e bagunçados

Comment: Qual é o fluxo da chamada? É sua aplicação c++ que vai chamar uma biblioteca c#, ou é uma interface c# que chama uma biblioteca c++?

Comment: Basicamente você precisa de uma interface, um método que te permita acessar o valor da variável. Depois compilar o código `c++` como uma biblioteca `dll` para que possa ser acessada dentro do código `c#`.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade c# chamando uma biblioteca em c++

Comment: Verifique esse artigo: [Using C++ in C# by Example](http://www.dorodnic.com/blog/2014/12/10/calling-cpp-by-example/).

Comment: Como vc quer fazer isso? Por dll (funciona, já fiz com delphi e c#)? vc que código fonte inline? Criar um projeto CLR na solution? (funciona, vc pode ter projetos de linguagens diferentes na mesma solution, C#,VB,C++)

Comment: @jean Sim mas eu preciso estabelecr uma comunicação entre os dois

Comment: Dlls se comunicam com .exe através de métodos que passem primitivas como parâmetros e retorno. Já se vc tiver dois projetos, um C++ e outro c# no visual studio talvez fique + fácil pois eles podem compartilhar classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu precisa fazer interop. Basicamente tu vai gerar uma dll em c++ expondo uma interface para ser consumida no c#. Na aplicação c# tu vai importar essa dll e então fazer a chamada do código nativo dentro do código gerenciado. No MSDN tem uma série ótima falando sobre o uso do Pinvoke.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyzhw3s8.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx.aspx

Palavras chaves para pesquisa: Pinvoke, Interop, dllimporter

Answer (score 0):

Já que é uma só variável, mantenha a variável do C++ salva em um XML e quando quiser obtê-la no c#, basta ler o xml. Essa ideia da interface pelo arquivo .dll é interessante ser usado em uma aplicação bem pesada.